# Iterate code through Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some basic code using `TextBlob` which extracts nouns from a body of text. I can apply this to a example text extract and return what I desire, for example:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
txt = """immunomodulatory roles of amyloid-beta and amyloid precursor protein"""

print([w for (w, pos) in TextBlob(txt).pos_tags if pos[0] == 'N'])
```

and this returns:

```
['roles', 'amyloid-beta', 'amyloid', 'precursor', 'protein']
```

I want to now apply this to a **single column in a Pandas df** so that the column will then only contain the outputted nouns and not the original inputted txt.

Any help would be much appreciated :)
Many thanks!

Comment: can you share the pandas data frame please

Comment: Make a little function out of it and use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the column?

Comment: @Timus Do you know would this be done? I am new to python and pandas sorry

Comment: @Timus, no worries I figured it out. The `.map()`  worked! Thank you :)